# Grep doesn't work correctly with .as files

Tags: actionscript-3, unix, grep

Here's the statement I'm running:

```
grep -i -H 'ConfigureControls' *.as
```

Note that I'm forcing file names with the `-H` flag.

What I get back is:

```
}       }   trac}   }   this.chairControls.debug.appendText("\nAn error occured when communicating with server:\n" + err.message);l);his.chairXML.storeResult;
{ackage {ublic cpublic frequest = new URLRequest(this.chairXML.store);to: " + this.chairXML.store;noll
```

No filename, and the text also looks very mangled (`package` has become `{ackage`, for example). What's going on?

Comment: Could you paste an example of your `.as` file

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me
`grep --version
GNU grep 2.5.4`
Check environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're grepping old Mac (OS <= 9) CR eol-style files on a machine that's expecting LF (unix) or CR/LF (DOS/Windows).

In that case, it's actually grepping properly but your terminal is interpreting the CR newlines as "move the cursor to the start of the line" without advancing to an empty line while displaying.

If you're on a unix-like system (OSX should work too), try converting the eol-style:

```
grep 'pattern' file | tr '\r' '\n'
```

If that works, you can actually convert the file's eol-style with:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file.as > fixed-file.as
```

Comment: Is there a fix besides going into every single file and changing the line endings?

Comment: Most modern editors have settings for that.  Make sure it's saving as Unix (or DOS even).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline has more information and suggested conversion programs.

Comment: Also, if you are transferring the files from a non-Unix system to Unix with FTP, make sure your client is set to transfer in ASCII mode for .as files, it should automatically convert the eol-style.

Comment: Unfortunately, piping to tr doesn't work – it just prints out all the .as files in the directory. I think my best bet at this point would be to write a shell script that implements your second suggestion.

Comment: There are links to converter programs at the Wikipedia link.  Install flip and you can just pass it a wildcard, or `find . -name '*.as' -print0 | xargs -0 flip -u` to convert everything below the current directory (or change . to a specific path).